# solidity call and delegatecall caller address

Tags: solidity

I'm working on an ERC721 contract and am trying to implement an `adminBurn` function from another smart contract. The purpose is to let users burn the token via the specific smart contract (admin contract) deployed.

However, regardless of using `call` or `delegatecall`, the caller address is always the `msg.sender` address instead of the `adminContract` address.

Would you mind informing me what the problem is?

The ERC721 contract is as follows:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;
...
contract test is ERC721 {
...
    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(tx.origin == adminContract, "transaction is not sent from an admin 
    contract for ERC721");
        _;
    }

    function adminBurn(
        uint256 tokenId
    ) external onlyAdmin {
        _burn(tokenId);
    }

    function setAdminContractAddress(address _adminContract) external onlyOwner{
        adminContract = _adminContract;
        emit adminContractSet(adminContract);
    }
}
```

And the admin contract is as follows:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;
...
contract adminContract is Ownable{
...
    function _callAdminBurn(address _ERC721, uint256 id) internal {
        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("adminBurn(uint256)",id);
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = _ERC721.call(payload);
        emit adminBurnByCall(_acceptedERC1155, success, result);
    }

    function _delegatecallAdminBurn(address _ERC721, uint256 id) internal {
        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("adminBurn(uint256)",id);
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = _ERC721.delegatecall(payload);
        emit adminBurnByCall(_acceptedERC1155, success, result);
    }


}
```

Comment: Problems solved.
for onlyAdmin modifier, use `msg.sender` instead of `tx.origin`.

Comment: `tx.origin` can never be a contract  because it must be an EOA (a wallet with peg for gas that invokes the tx)